# how can i install react native on window command?

Tags: reactjs, native, uuid, chokidar, svgo

[i tried to install ***'npm install --global expo-cli'*** and i get this error. svgo@1.3.2 this svgo is no longer supported. upgrade to v2.x.x, uuid@3.4.0 please upgrade to version 7 or higher, chokidar@2.1.8: chokidar 2 does not receive security update since 2019. i run ***npm audit fix --force***, it said recommended protection disable and 7 packages are looking for funding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0KLn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are warns regarding libraries you are downloading from the web, don't be concerned by them, you cannot fix those issues. Just ignore it and start using expo. Everything is installed fine. Same errors appear when installing plain React project from the official source, you just need to ignore those warnings.

Comment: okay thanks but how do i know whether its been installed because am used to seeing npm start as signal that it has installed

Comment: @Yero just type `expo --version` into your terminal and you should see if your computer recognizes the command correctly

Comment: it say expo version 6.0.2

Comment: @Yero then what is the problem? expo is working, create the project and happy coding!